# Having problems sending an order to the server

Tags: android

So I am struggling on a bit of code and any help would be greatly appriciated, I tried to do most of the leg work myself prior to posting the question so I assure you I am not looking for someone to do my work for me... just need help getting it to work.

I have a simple shopper app that I am trying to get it to send the order to a database and I check if it is sent by checking the database through visual studio.

Problem is, my app works but there is nothing appearing in visual studio registering that it has received the order. I think there may be a problem with my code and it is having difficulty sending the order.

If it helps any this is what my assignment is asking me to do for this step:

> Now we need to work on the Checkout activity, and submit the order to
>   the server. Go to  CheckoutActivity class and add a new method called
>   checkoutOrder().   In this method you should define an AsyncTask and
>   then execute it. (Note: the method getApplication() can be called
>   directly, you are already inside an Activity so you don’t need an
>   “activity” object as a parameter).

Here is the code I have so far in the checkout activity:

```
package uk.ac.uk.st265.shopper;

    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;

    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

    public class CheckoutActivity extends Activity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            setupActionBar();
        }

        /**
         * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
         */
        private void setupActionBar() {

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.checkout, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
                // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
                // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
                // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
                //
                // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back

                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        protected void checkoutOrder() {
            String url = String.format(MainActivity.WEBSERVER_PUTORDER,
                    ((ShopperApp) getApplication()).getOrderString());

            // start an async task to submit the order
            AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // Extract as JSON
                    JSONObject obj = null;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    try {
                        // the first parameter is the URL we should use
                        URL u = new URL(params[0]);
                        // establish the connection
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u
                                .openConnection();
                        conn.connect();
                        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) // it is not http ok
                                                            // there is a problem on
                                                            // the server
                            return null;
                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                        // read the stream
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                        while (is.read(buffer) != -1)
                            bytestream.write(buffer);

                        // extract as JSON
                        String jsonStr = new String(bytestream.toByteArray());

                        JSONObject Object = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        //obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        return obj;


                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return obj;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
                    TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_results);
                    if (result != null) {
                        resultText.setText("Thank you for shopping with us! \n Your order has been placed.");
                        ((ShopperApp)getApplication()).cart.clear();
                    } else {
                        resultText.setText("There seems to be a problem with your order.");
                    }
                }

        };
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you created the `AsyncTask`, but you never executed it:

task.execute();

See the [documentation on execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29). You'll find a code example at the top of the page.

Comment: I just added a task.execute(url); in the correct part of my code hoping this will fix it... and it still doesnt seem to want to work.

Comment: I don't know about further problems, but if you don't execute a task, it will not run by itself :-) . Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the help anyway, I did not notice that I did not have an  execute task so it is a good thing you pointed it out. I was just hoping that would be the problem and it would fix it. 

Cheers for your help though :)